# What is the downside for covered call options?

Tags: call-options, risk

What is the downside of selling covered calls on the stocks or ETFs you own that have appreciated significantly from their original purchase price?

Answer (score 1):

When you sell a covered call you get premium upfront in exchange for capping your profit.

If the stock is above the strike at expiry, the loss from the option you sold will be offset exactly by the gain in the stock.

If the stock goes down significantly, the call you sold will be worthless (which is good for you), but the stock itself will lose value (which is bad). Since the most you can profit from the option is the premium, your losses are unlimited.

You need to make sure you have the appropriate risk management measures in place (e.g. put a stop loss on the call) in case the stock moves against you.

Answer (score 1):

The downside is missing out on upside.

Writing/selling covered calls limits your upside potential, if the share price moves beyond your strike you either have to buy back the short call for a loss or let it get exercised and sell the shares for less than current price.

You'd also have to think about whether timing of the sale of these shares is optimal (short-term vs long-term capital gains).

If you are selling covered calls because you believe the underlying has limited additional upside, then it's also wise to consider whether or not you even want to hold the underlying anymore.

There's no additional downside risk to selling covered calls vs just holding the shares.

Answer (score 0):

The downside of selling a covered call:

- Opportunity loss if the stock zooms up past your short strike
- If your choice was to sell the covered call for income instead of the selling the stock then you'd have actual loss if the stock dropped a lot.
- Possible taxation if your short call is assigned